# Vuejs vue-property-decorator data field declaration

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

new to Vue.

Making use of `vue-property-decorator` & also tried `vue-class-component`.

According to github (https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator), `data` objects are declared plainly within class, for example `ecosystem`:

```
  import {Component, Vue} from 'vue-property-decorator';

  @Component({
     components: {}
  })
  export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
      ecosystem: [
        {
          text: 'vuetify-loader',
          href: 'https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader'
        },
        {
          text: 'github',
          href: 'https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify'
        },
        {
          text: 'awesome-vuetify',
          href: 'https://github.com/vuetifyjs/awesome-vuetify'
        }
      ] 
  }
```

instead of

```
  data() {
    return {
      ecosystem: ['bla', 'bla', 'bla']
    }
  }
```

However when i try to use it, getting the error `Property or method "ecosystem" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

calling to

```
  created() {
    console.log(this.ecosystem)
  }
```

also returns `undefined`

What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see running sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/y2nop643xv

declare ecosytem like this:

```
ecosystem: any = [
    {
      text: "vuetify-loader";
      href: "https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader";
    },
    {
      text: "github";
      href: "https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify";
    },
    {
      text: "awesome-vuetify";
      href: "https://github.com/vuetifyjs/awesome-vuetify";
    }
  ];
```

and a little tip, try to avoid the usage of any, you are using typescript, use typed objects

Comment: OMG yeah blind personal mistake, happens :D